# Page editor adds "<>"

Tags: publishing-page, html, html-editor

I keep having this issue where everytime I save a page, SharePoint 2010 adds "<>" several times.

Each subsequent save adds more tags. In the HTML they are represented as

```
&lt;&gt;
```

and look like this:

```
<><><><>
<><><><>
<><><><>
<><><><> 
<><><><>​ 
<><><><>
```

Is there an issue with my HTML that is cause SharePoint to automatically add these tags? Or is this a known issue in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: I believe this is a glitch with Sharepoint 2010. I've had the same issue arise randomly a few times.

Comment: Any idea what causes it?

Comment: Teddy I did a little research and came up with nothing. I believe the way i resolved my issue was removing the webpart and re-adding it.